# ng-include content replace from ng-include dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am very new to angular, need some help this problem..

top-header.html

```
<div class="row">
<some default html contents goes here>
  <breadcrumbs-extras>

  </breadcrumbs-extras>
</div>
```

page.html

```
<div class="page-header" data-ng-include="'tpl/top-header.html'">
<div class="col s12 m6 l6 right-align ">
    <a href="#/in" class="btn blue lighten-1 white-text z-depth-0">
      <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload
    </a>
    <a href="#/inv" class="btn green lighten-1 white-text z-depth-0">
      <i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i> Reorder
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the contents of page-header div to be copied to breadcrumbs-extras directive,

How can I achieve this...

Comment: Are you looking for ngTransclude (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)?

Comment: can I use ngTranclude with ng-include

Comment: No, it can only be used with directives. From what I understand of your question you want the breadcrumb to dynamically change depending on the content of the page-header div, correct? If so, you might be better using `scope.$emit` to get certain contents up to the navigation level. Also take a look at https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb